# Include a Promisified Callback Inside A Promise Resolver?

Tags: node.js, promise, node-promisify

I'm setting up a GraphQL resolver to call a Braintree endpoint. The Braintree npm package wants to call their endpoint with code that looks like this:

```
braintreeGateway.customer.create({
    firstName: "Jen",
    lastName: "Smith",
    company: "Braintree",
    email: "jen@example.com",
    phone: "312.555.1234",
    fax: "614.555.5678",
    website: "www.example.com"
}, function (err, result) {
    result.success;
    result.customer.id;
});
```

GraphQL resolvers return promises. I'm trying to figure out how to promisify this callback, and include it within a promise resolver.

I've read a lot of SO posts about promisifying a callback, but the ones I've found so far don't seem to quite match up to this use case.

I've tried a lot of things, this being the latest:

```
getBrainTreeCustomerId: (parent, args, context) => {
    const userid = context.userId;

    const braintreeCustomerCreate =  util.promisify(braintreeGateway.customer.create);

    async function run_braintreeCustomerCreate() {
        try {
            let braintreeCustomerId = await braintreeCustomerCreate({
                firstName: "Jen",
                lastName: "Smith",
                company: "Braintree",
                email: "jen@example.com",
                phone: "312.555.1234",
                fax: "614.555.5678",
                website: "www.example.com"
            });
            return braintreeCustomerId
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('ERROR:', err);
        }
    }

    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            let braintreeCustomerId = (async () => {
                let braintreeCustomerId = await run_braintreeCustomerCreate()
                return braintreeCustomerId;
            })();
            return braintreeCustomerId;
        })
        .then((braintreeCustomerId) => {
            return braintreeCustomerId;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
}
```

But the catch handler gets an error saying "Cannot read property '_createSignature' of undefined".

What's the correct syntax to use here?

Comment: which catch handler gets hit? the one in the `try` of `run_braintreeCustomerCreate` or the `.catch` after in the `Promise.resolve()` chain?

Comment: It's the one in the `try` of `run_braintreeCustomerCreate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the promisified function outside of the scope of the gateway you might be separating it too much from the `BrainTree` object structure. The error sounds like it's trying to access another internal function that's no longer in scope.  Try this instead without using `util.promisify`:

```
async function run_braintreeCustomerCreate() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    braintreeGateway.customer.create( 
      {
        firstName: "Jen",
        lastName: "Smith",
        company: "Braintree",
        email: "jen@example.com",
        phone: "312.555.1234",
        fax: "614.555.5678",
        website: "www.example.com"
      },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve(result);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

This will return a Promise that either resolves or rejects based on the result of the call while calling in a way consistent with the object.

Another way that **may** work would be to add the promisified function to the customer object like this:

```
const createAsPromise = util.promisify(braintreeGateway.customer.create);
braintreeGateway.customer.createAsPromise = createAsPromise;

async function run_braintreeCustomerCreate() {
  try {
    let braintreeCustomerId = await braintreeGateway.customer.createAsPromise(
      { /* data */ }
    ); 
    return braintreeCustomerId;
  }
  catch(err) console.log('ERROR:', err);
}
```

As a general note, you don't need to do catching earlier in the chain as the `.catch` will work and it simplifies your logic by removing the need for the `try` at all. Also note that the object returned from the `create` call will contain an Id but is not itself just the Id - it's an object. In fact having the `try` with `catch` there will block the error from being seen by whoever calls it because it will end up returning nothing (ie, `undefined`) as the resolved value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `this` value is not bound in the `create` method if you don't call the promisified function as a method.

```
const braintreeCustomerCreate = util.promisify(braintreeGateway.customer.create.bind(braintreeGateway.customer));
//                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

getBrainTreeCustomerId: async (parent, args, context) => {
    const userid = context.userId;

    try {
        let braintreeCustomerId = await braintreeCustomerCreate({
            firstName: "Jen",
            lastName: "Smith",
            company: "Braintree",
            email: "jen@example.com",
            phone: "312.555.1234",
            fax: "614.555.5678",
            website: "www.example.com"
        });
        return braintreeCustomerId;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('ERROR:', err);
        return null;
    }
}
```